# Flow not populating values on new record creation

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

I have written a record triggered flow that creates a new record on child object every time the parent record is updated. The child object will gets it value from Parent object. When I debug the flow with test record I can see child record creation with values populated. But after I activated the flow I can see only few fields are populated and remaining are not populated with values from Parent record. I checked the FLS and it is fine. What else could be the reason?

Added screenshot of Create Record element for reference
[image]

Comment: Just to confirm are you assigning the field with the parent field in the flow. If possible can you share the screenshot of the new record creation element.

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala, I have attached screenshot above. Please check.

Comment: use debug log to see what values are available to flow when it executes (and also whether other processes are clearing values)

Comment: So the fields like Buyer_Type__c are not populating in child record? Is this happening only on create scenario or in update scenario as well.

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala, The field Buyer Type alone is not populating and all the remaining field values are populating. This is happening during both Create and Update record. Also, the field Buyer Type is no referenced anywhere else, except the current flow.

Comment: Can you confirm what type of field is it? Is it picklist value in both the objects?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala, There is another flow that is updating the values on 'After Update/Insert' logic. I failed to notice the additional flow.  The Order of Execution for the flows is not managed properly and hence this issue. Thanks for the help!